# Linked lists: Why isn't my recursive sublist checker working?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, sublist, frequency-analysis

The idea is to find segments of the second linked list that are identical to the first linked list, and add whichever node directly follows to a list that will be returned. So, if my first linked list is
`h -> e -> y -> None`
and my second is
`h -> e -> y -> d -> u -> d -> e -> None`
my output should be `[d]`.

I've verified that the linked lists have been created properly, but will just add their contents as comments to keep things simple:

```
def find_sublist(list_start_node, corpus_start_node, output=[]):
    if corpus_start_node is None:
        return output
    elif list_start_node is None:
        output.append(corpus_start_node.item)
        return find_sublist(myList.head, corpus_start_node)
    elif list_start_node.item is corpus_start_node.item:
        return find_sublist(list_start_node.next_node, corpus_start_node.next_node)
    else:
        return find_sublist(myList.head, corpus_start_node.next_node)

# myList: 3 -> 7 -> None
# myCorpus: 3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 2 -> 34 -> 77 -> 21 -> 3 -> 7 -> 9 -> 2 -> 34 -> 88 -> 9 -> None

print(find_sublist(myList.head, myCorpus.head))
```

The bottom print function prints an output list of `[8]`, when I should be getting `[8, 9]`. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: `list_start_node.item is corpus_start_node.item` should probably be `list_start_node.item == corpus_start_node.item`, but I don't think that's what's wrong.

Comment: @Dennis okay, thanks very much for that anyway!

Comment: It is maybe not the cause of your problem, but a mutable default argument is not a good idea; you should avoid `..., output=[]):` in most cases.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque okay, why is that? Thanks for the tip! I've tried this with an external list as well, and got the same problem, so yeah, it's not the core issue here!

Comment: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: @ReblochonMasque hmm, this seems to indicate that what's problematic about it is that people are usually trying to avoid precisely what I'm trying to do with it! I'll keep that in mind for the future though!

Comment: Yes, you're trying to use the parameter as a cache for the traversal. But there is nothing to empty that cache after the traversal is done. It also generally makes the code harder to reason about. Normally with recursion, what you would do is take the result back from the recursive call and combine it with the current result, rather than trying to store the current result and let the recursive call do the combination.

Comment: That said, I don't see how this problem really calls for recursion. An iterative approach seems very straightforward.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the iterative approach I originally came up with was very big and ugly (I'm relatively new to computer science!). What would your general iterative approach be? Thanks for that advice so far, that makes sense actually.

Comment: What should be the output when finding `1->0->1` in `1->0->1->0->1->2` , i.e. when there are overlapping matches? Your algorithm seems not designed for spotting those.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you need to make two checks when you find the first value in the corpus that matches your target list. First you need to check if the rest of the target list matches. And second, you need to check the rest of the corpus for the whole main list. Unfortunately, you don't really want to use the same recursive function for both, or you'll match the end of the target list anywhere they appear (regardless of whether they follow the earlier parts). Maybe you could add a flag to stop that, but it would be conceptually simpler with a separate function.

```
def matcher(needle, haystack):
    if haystack is None:  # failure case #1, we've run out of haystack
        return None
    if needle is None:    # success case, return the next haystack item
        return haystack.item
    if needle.item != haystack.item:  # falure case #2, a mismatch
        return None
    return matcher(needle.next_node, haystack.next_node)  # recurse

def searcher(needle, haystack, results=None):
    if results is None:   # avoid using a mutable default argument
        results = []

    if haystack is None:  # base case, we've searched the whole haystack
        return results

    match = matcher(needle, haystack) # test current position in haystack
    if match is not None:
        results.append(match)

    return searcher(needle, haystack.next_node, results)  # recurse
```

Note that since both of these functions are tail recursive, you can easily turn them into loops, and if you want, nest the loops in a single function:

```
def iterative_search_and_match(needle, haystack):
    results = []
    while needle and haystack:  # search loop
        match_needle = needle
        match_haystack = haystack
        while match_needle and match_haystack:  # match loop
            if match_needle.item != match_haystack.item:
                break
            match_needle = match_needle.next_node
            match_haystack = match_haystack.next_node
        else:  # this doesn't run if the break was hit!
            if match_haystack:
                results.append(match_haystack.item)
        needle = needle.next_node
        haystack = haystack.next_node
    return results
```

Comment: One tricky case might be when `needle` matches `haystack` at the of the linked list. Then `if match is not None` cannot distinguish between success and failure. I might be just overthinking though, because OP didn't specify such an edge case.

Comment: @j1-lee: Yeah, I treat that as a failure because there's nothing to return (no value past the end of the match).

Answer (score 0):

I translated your function and it seems to work as expected. Is it possible there is some problem with your linked list setup?

```py
# Setup
start_corpus = None
for x in reversed([3, 7, 8, 2, 34, 77, 21,
                   3, 7, 9, 2, 34, 88, 9]):
    start_corpus = (x, start_corpus)

start_word = (3, (7, None))

##################

def find_sublist(word, corpus):
    if corpus is None:
        return
    elif word is None:
        yield corpus[0]
        yield from find_sublist(start_word, corpus)
    elif word[0] == corpus[0]:
        yield from find_sublist(word[1], corpus[1])
    else:
        yield from find_sublist(start_word, corpus[1])

print(list(find_sublist(start_word, start_corpus)))
# [8, 9]
```

Comment: While it generates the right answer in this situation, it doesn't work generally. It returns the numbers that appear in the corpus after a `7`, as long as there's one `3` somewhere before it. That's not what is desired.

Comment: @Blckknght Changing the input to [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 7] makes in print []

Comment: Note that the last expression is `find_sublist(start_word, corpus[1])`, not `find_sublist(word[1], corpus[1])`. There is, however, a problem if your word is long and you get a partial match: it could skip over bits contained in that partial match. That isn't a problem with the needle [3, 7] though.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right. Using a global like that is really sketchy (I know, you inherited it from the questioner's code), but it does work.

Comment: Thanks very much Dennis. It turns out it was the way I had implemented the linked lists after all. Next time I have a question I won't trust my little experiments so much!